# How do I UNION the results of two queries in SQLite3 for python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to do multiple search functions for the user, and would like to know how to combine their results.

I tried the 'obvious' way to do it, which was just to use the

```
cursor.execute("UNION")
```

between the two methods.
But that didn't work, and gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\T3AJM\T3_AJM_fn.py", line 188, in <module>
    welcome_menu()
  File "C:\T3AJM\T3_AJM_fn.py", line 119, in welcome_menu
    file_server.master_search(answer[0])
  File "C:\T3AJM\T3_AJM_fn.py", line 51, in master_search
    cursor.execute("UNION")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "UNION": syntax error
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
search_file_name(search)
cursor.execute("UNION")
search_by_extension(search)
```

And have the two results be combined.

The methods would be something like

```
def search_file_name(self, searched_file_name):
    """
    Searches
    """
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM files
    WHERE file_name LIKE ?""", ('%' + searched_file_name + '%',))
```

and

```
def search_by_extension(self, extension):
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM files
    WHERE extension LIKE ?""", ('%' + extension + '%',))
```

I know that I can technically do it by using the multi flag in execute, and manually copy the strings from both methods into one, but I want to be able to do this for any number of search methods, and not have to do that every time.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"I'm trying to do multiple search functions for the user, and would like to know how to combine their results."* - This part is unclear. Multiple "SQL-equivalent" searches (same SQL code, different parameters)? Or is it different SQL/different tables every time? Is combining the results in Python not an option?

Comment: @Tomalak Multiple SQL searches. There are examples in the original post with the relevant code. I want to be able to do something like
```
method()
execute("UNION")
another_method()
```
And be able to display the combination of the results.

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.execute()` does not do batch processing. It takes a single, complete SQL statement and executes it. A lone `"UNION"` is not a complete SQL statement, it's a syntax error.

This would work.

```
cursor.execute("""
SELECT stuff FROM table1 WHERE something = 'this_value'
UNION
SELECT stuff FROM table2 WHERE something_else = 'that_value'
""")
```

But combining multiple query results in Python directly would also work, depending on what you do

---

So for your case, this would be one way (single statement through UNION):

```
# Avoid SELECT *. Spell out the columns you're selecting.

cursor.execute("""
SELECT path, name, extension FROM files WHERE file_name LIKE ?1
UNION
SELECT path, name, extension FROM files WHERE extension LIKE ?1
""", ('%' + extension + '%',))
```

And this would be another (combine afterwards):

```
from itertools import chain

def search_file_name(self, searched_file_name):
    return cursor.execute("""
    SELECT path, name, extension FROM files WHERE file_name LIKE ?1
    """, ('%' + searched_file_name + '%',))

def search_by_extension(self, extension):
    return cursor.execute("""
    SELECT path, name, extension FROM files WHERE extension LIKE ?1
    """, ('%' + extension + '%',))

def search_combined(self, criteria):
    return chain(
        self.search_file_name(self, criteria),
        self.search_by_extension(self, criteria)
    )
```

Comment: That block is specifically what I don't want to do, as it would require changing the searches themselves. I can think of ways to do it without having to worry about that, but it seems extremely un-pythonic to do something like that. Combining in python would be possible because execute returns an iterator of all the stuff it finds, but I was hoping to do at least most of the search logic within SQL.

Comment: Regarding *"but it seems extremely un-pythonic to do something like that"* - That depends. Using a UNION query when it's appropriate to do so not unpythonic. For example, it gives you the ability to do complex and efficient sorting directly in the database, which is something that simply chaining a couple of query results will not do. It all depends on the circumstances.

Comment: I could be incorrect, but I don't think that works either. One of the reasons that I wanted to use UNION was to not have repeating answers, and be able to still search those results in SQL. This just gives a generator, which defeats the entire purpose of using SQL as a storage and search method in the first place. I could probably convert that generator to a table, but it seems awfully wasteful to go from SQL table ->generator->SQL table.

Comment: Well then you will have to go with the UNION query. There is no other way.

Comment: I was saying your answer was un-pythonic, not UNION. UNION would be wonderful in this scenario, as if I knew a method to insert commands like I listed above easily, then there are other problems that I would be able to apply that logic to.

Comment: I was specifically asking how to use UNION. The reason I asked this was because I don't know of a clean way to do UNION on two or more separate execute statements.

Comment: My answer is not "un-pythonic". You want something that is impossible. When the database is done with the query and you have the results as a Python data structure, then there is no way to UNION them unless you implement the equivalent of a UNION operation yourself, in one way or the other. UNION is an SQL operation. You have a choice to do *all of it* in the database, or *none of it*. There is no middle ground.

Comment: That sounds like you don't really believe me. :)